# Logging Page popup in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The "Logging Page - Log" keeps popping up as I type in Oracle SQL Developer. I think I must have accidentally hit a shortcut and enabled some setting, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 2):

go to tools->preferences->environment->log->set maximum log files to 0

Comment: logging page still appears, just with no info in it

Answer (score 0):

What version are you running? If you're on the latest and greatest, that window should stay suppressed until you open/dock it back - unless you're running the app in Debug mode.

Comment: Version 3.2.20.09
It seems to pop up after I finish typing certain column names. I tried resarting the program, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Try upgrading to version 4.0.2

Comment: I can't, its a company computer. Also, it only started doing this today, after several month using it.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this myself. Turns out my session was disconnected and the log was reporting a socket error. What do the entries say?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to suppress it, it will pop up again on any action. However you can dock it in the left bottom area and it'll stay on the "Messages" tab unless you click the other tab.